# How to change text font family in new window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the "hello" text default font to my custom font. I imported the font to the style tag using @font-face and I set the font-family of the text to my font but it's not changing the font, I still get the default h1 font.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face { font-family: "MotivaLight"; src: url('motiva-sans/MotivaSansLight.woff.ttf'); }
    </style>
    <h1 style="font-family: MotivaLight;">Hi</h1>
    <button onclick="c()">open</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function c() {
            var win = window.open("")
            win.document.documentElement.innerHTML=`<body><style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family: "MotivaLight"; src: url('motiva-sans/MotivaSansLight.woff.ttf'); } h1{font-family: MotivaLight;}</style><h1>hello</h1></body>`
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

my folder is like this :

```
website
|
├─ motiva-sans
|       └──────── MotivaSansLight.woff.ttf
└─ index.html
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: "but it's not changing" – what *is* happening in the new window, then? Do you see a 404 from the font not being able to load? Are your styles even applied?

Comment: You should place `<style>` elements in the document `<head>`.

Comment: it's only not changing the font to mine, still the default h1 font on the new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put a / in front of the path to take the directory from root.

```
@font-face { font-family: "MotivaLight"; src: url('/motiva-sans/MotivaSansLight.woff.ttf'); }
```

Comment: I tried it on both font-face but it's still not working

Comment: Thanks, that helped me finding the solution, you were right, the file path has to be `file:///C:/path/to/file/font.ttf'` and can't be from the directory.